# What is the best way to input an xml file into sql Server database

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a xml file that looks like this below

The format of the Xml file is the same but there are many more

```
<id>220</id>
<direction>1</direction>
<count>1</count>
<date>2017-10-05T00:00:00</date> in the actual Xml file
```

Here is the Xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<counts>
<count>
<id>220</id>
<direction>1</direction>
<count>1</count>
<date>2017-10-05T00:00:00</date>
</count>
<count>
<id>220</id>
<direction>2</direction>
<count>0</count>
<date>2017-10-05T00:00:00</date>
</count>
<counts>

I first tried to copy this Xml file into Json format and this work fine creating this json file
{"counts":{"count":[
{"id":220,"direction":1,"count":1,"date":"2017-10-05T00:00:00"},
{"id":220,"direction":2,"count":0,"date":"2017-10-05T00:00:00"},
]}}
```

The problem start when I try to map because the map in data factory looks like this

[image]

So only one record from json is added to the database table.
So I wonder what is the best way to go.

1. One solution could be if it is possible to change the json file that is looks like this
   {"id":220,"direction":1,"count":1,"date":"2017-10-05T00:00:00"}
   {"id":220,"direction":2,"count":0,"date":"2017-10-05T00:00:00"}

Both the xml file and the json file is a blob in different container in azure.
So If it's possible to change the blob json file how could I do that.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Hey @tony, you can use advance editor and select the configurations as shown in [this image](https://i.imgur.com/v7LcRH5.png) to get [required json file](https://i.imgur.com/drp9RhS.png).

Comment: But it doesn't work to maually edit the json file. When the ADF is run it should be load the json into the database table automatically without anyone edit the file.

Comment: Does the schema of the XML keep changing?

Comment: No the schema is the same with that I mean the format but the nuber of object in the array is different.

Comment: So, you can use this mapping. Anytime you want to use this copy activity, there is no need to change the mapping everytime. It should work for any number of objects

Comment: It only takes the first record in the json becuse the mapping is like this $['counts']['count'][0]['id']

Comment: @tony : a similar thread : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1185087/data-factory-xml-validation(copy-activity)-throwin
hope this can help you

Comment: @tony, refer to the images that I have provided in the first image. Using advance editor would help

Comment: Many thanks to all of you who have helped me because now I can load the xml file into a sql server database table.

Answer (score 0):

- You can use the advance editor in the mapping after importing the schema to achieve the requirement. I have the following data in my xml file:

[image]

- Now, I chose the file pattern for my JSON sink as Array of objects and then use import schema. There you can see advance editor option. Enable it and select `count` array from drop down which will result in the following mapping (give sink names as required):

[image]

- Now, when you run the pipeline, you will get the desired result. The following is the image of final data:

[image]